# ngx-bootstrap: Typeahead , Error expecting Observable

Tags: angular, typeahead, ngx-bootstrap

Getting this Error when ever I type more 3 characters in input box.

TypeError: You provided an invalid object where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.

.html file :

```
<input class="form-control"
           type="text"
           [typeahead]="dataSourceObservable"
           typeaheadOptionField="address1"
           typeaheadGroupField="city"
           [typeaheadMinLength]="3"
           (typeaheadOnSelect)="setAddress($event)"
           id="{{componentId}}"
           maxlength="100"
           allowedPattern="^[a-zA-Z0-9\s\.\-\#]*$"
           appPatternRestrict
           [formControl]="componentFormControl"
           [(ngModel)]="quoteReference[jsonField]"
           [typeaheadOptionsLimit]="20"
           [appDisableControl]="componentDetails.locked"
           placeholder=" "
    />
```

.ts file :

```
public dataSourceObservable: Observable<any>;


  constructor(public quoteDataService: QuoteDataService, public addressPrefillService: AddressPrefillService, public store$: Store<State>) {
    super(quoteDataService, store$);
    // Required for type ahead for values, do not remove unless thoroughly tested.
    this.dataSourceObservable = Observable.create(() => {})
  }


  ngOnInit() {
    this.componentFormControl.valueChanges
      .subscribe(value => {
        let address = null;
        this.store$.pipe(select(currentQuote)).pipe(take(1)).subscribe(val=>{
          if(val ) {
            if(val.garageAddress) {
              address = val.garageAddress;
            }
          }
        });
        if (address && address.zipCode !== null) {
          let request = {
            "zipCode": address.zipCode,
            "addressLine1": value
          };
          this.dataSourceObservable = this.addressPrefillService.prefillAddress(request);
        }
      });
  }
```

[Expected Behaviour](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L3wwF.png)
[Error In Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CtMkf.png)

Comment: please add `this.dataSourceObservable = this.addressPrefillService.prefillAddress(request);` defination

Answer (score 0):

The version of `ngx-bootstrap` your using might affect the error your getting so first things first, make sure your using the latest version

The error only appears after 3 characters because of the `[typeaheadMinLength]="3"` property in your template, once the 3rd character is entered it will then try to update the bound value.

The `typeahead` does not have to be an Observable, taken from the ngx-bootstrap [docs](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/typeahead):

> options source, can be Array of strings, objects or an Observable for external matching process

So for the purpose of testing/dev it would be easier to use a simple Array like `["one", "two", "three"]` instead of an empty Observable for your components `dataSourceObservable` property (their first example does this).

As for the error your receiving, it looks like your not using an actual Observable object, the `Observable.create` method must not actually return an Observable as the Typeahead expects, causing the error.

I'm not sure what library that `Observable` object is coming from in your code but I'll assume it's `rxjs`, possibly an older version, in versions 6+ there are different ways of creating an Observable, one way:

```
import { of } from 'rxjs';
of({}); // Makes Observable with empty object as data
```

I'd suggest reading up on rxjs basics in the Angular docs - https://angular.io/guide/rx-library